# How to match callable objects out of parameter pack to corresponding element in an array as argument?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

For example, say I have the following:

```
template<typename ...FunctionTypes>
static void MainFunction(FunctionTypes... functions) 
{
    constexpr Uint32_t NumFunctions= sizeof...(FunctionTypes);

    std::array<double, NumFunctions> myArray;
    double arg1 = 4.2;
    int arg2= 9;
    for_each_tuple(myArray, FigureOutThisPart(myFunctions, arg1, arg2)...);
}
```

Where `for_each_tuple` takes a tuple or array of size `N` as well as `N` functions to apply to each tuple entry. This part was tricky to implement, but works! It is defined as such:

```
namespace detail {
template <typename Tuple, std::size_t ...Indices, typename ...FunctionTypes>
constexpr void for_each_tuple_impl(Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Indices...>, FunctionTypes&&... functionsIn) {
    std::tuple<FunctionTypes...> functions = std::tie(functionsIn...);
    using swallow = int[];
    (void)swallow{
        1, // Make sure array has at least one element
        (std::get<Indices>(functions)(std::get<Indices>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), void(), int{})...
    };
}
}
template <typename Tuple, typename ...Functions>
void for_each_tuple(Tuple&& tuple, Functions&&... f) {
    constexpr std::size_t N = std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>::value;
    static_assert(N == sizeof...(Functions), "Need one function per tuple entry");
    detail::for_each_tuple_impl(
        std::forward<Tuple>(tuple),
        std::make_index_sequence<N>{},
        std::forward<Functions>(f)...);
}
```

The idea is that I have set of `myFunctions`, each of which is operating on a different entry of `myArray`. Each function in `myFunctions` would take `arg1`, `arg2`, and the current array entry as arguments.

My goal is to be able to pass `arg1` and `arg2` into each of `myFunctions` so that those values can be used in the operation on the current array entry. Is there a sane way in which this can be done? Ideally, I would like the solution to be a constexpr so everything can get resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like this could work:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <functional>

template<typename ...FunctionTypes>
constexpr void MainFunction(FunctionTypes... functions) 
{
    constexpr auto NumFunctions= sizeof...(FunctionTypes);

    std::array<double, NumFunctions> myArray{};//Zero-init for now.
    double arg1 = 4.2;
    int arg2= 9;

    std::size_t i=0;
    (std::invoke(functions, arg1,arg2, myArray[i++]),...);
}
```

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(double a1, int a2, int a){
    std::cout<<"Called foo("<<a1<<','<<a2<<','<<a<<")\n";
}

int main()
{
    MainFunction(foo,foo);
    return 0;
}
```

It requires C++17 for the fold expression and the sequence points for the comma.

It can be evaluated at compile-time:

```
constexpr void bar(double a1, int a2, int a){
}
int main()
{
    constexpr auto x = (MainFunction(bar,bar),1); // Force compile-time evaluation.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ohh, this is great! Checks all of my boxes and doesn't require changing too much of what I have. Many thanks!

Comment: @Danny Just be careful that there can be only one `i` expression in the call. You cannot index across two arrays with a single variable because the evaluation order of function arguments is unspecified and the increment makes that UB. In that case just use two separate variables.

Answer (score 2):

I would just make a tuple out of functors at very beginning and match an element of the tuple to a corresponding element of the array:

```cpp
template<std::size_t I, typename E, typename ...F, typename ...Args>
constexpr void apply(const std::array<E, sizeof...(F)>& elements,
                     const std::tuple<F...>& functions,
                     Args... args) {
    std::get<I>(functions)(std::get<I>(elements), args...);
}

template<std::size_t ...I, typename E, typename ...F, typename ...Args>
constexpr void for_each(std::index_sequence<I...>,
                        const std::array<E, sizeof...(I)>& elements,
                        const std::tuple<F...>& functions,
                        Args... args) {
    (apply<I>(elements, functions, args...),...);
}


template<typename ...F>
constexpr static void MainFunction(F... functors)
{
    constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(F);
    constexpr std::array<double, size> elements{};
    
    constexpr double arg1 = 4.2;
    constexpr int arg2 = 9;
    
    for_each(std::make_index_sequence<size>(),
             elements,
             std::forward_as_tuple(functors...),
             arg1, arg2);
    
}
```

The client code will look something like that:

```cpp
void function(double val, double arg1, int arg2) {
    std::cout << arg1 + arg2 + 8 * val << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    MainFunction(function, [](double val, double arg1, double arg2) {
        std::cout << val / arg1 + arg2 << std::endl;
    });
    return 0;
}
```

As long as argument functions are `constexpr`, the implementation is also `constexpr`:

```cpp
template<typename ...F>
constexpr static auto MainFunction(F... functors) { ... return elements;  }
constexpr void function(double val, double arg1, int arg2) { ... }

int main() {
    // Retrieves the constexpr elements array from the function
    constexpr auto val = MainFunction(function, [](double, double, int){ ... });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) to construct a function that will have placeholder arguments, which is a solution a little closer to what you originally intended. This, however, has a drawback of not being runnable in `constexpr` context:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N, typename T, typename... Functions>
auto for_each_tuple(std::array<T, N> const& array, Functions... functions) {
    auto index = 0uz;
    (std::invoke(functions, array[index++]), ...);
}

template<typename ...FunctionTypes>
static void MainFunction(FunctionTypes... functions)
{
    constexpr std::uint32_t NumFunctions= sizeof...(FunctionTypes);

    std::array<double, NumFunctions> myArray{};
    double arg1 = 4.2;
    int arg2= 9;
    for_each_tuple(myArray, std::bind_front(functions, arg1, arg2)...);
}

auto main() -> int {
    auto print_thrice = [](double d1, int i2, double arr) {
        std::cout << d1 << ' ' << i2 << ' ' << arr << '\n';
    };

    MainFunction(print_thrice, print_thrice, print_thrice);
}
```